# django-admin startproject error: No module named django-admin

Tags: python, django

I'm on windows 10, in command prompt i invoke:

`python -m django-admin startproject mysite`

And i got this error while trying with env:

> C:\Users\DR\Desktop\ChatMat\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named django-admin

Here is the error without env:

> C:\Users\DR\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: No module named django-admin

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: Btw im using windows 10

Comment: py -m pip install Django

Comment: I tried that still

Comment: Are you using pychar, pytorch etc?

Comment: Im using Windows 10 python 3.1.0

Comment: Is django newer version.? If yes, then it will not work on python 3.1.0

Comment: Im using django v4.2.2

Comment: Install python 3.11 not 3.12

Comment: Sorry i meant im using python v3.9.13

Comment: Here is link. scroll at bottom. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/install/